# Is it possible to go to the next page using Collection View and display data?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I'm the middle doing some project that involve CollectionView and property list. I want to do the image grid in the Collection View, and the image is the significance to proceed to the next page.

Here I want to do:

1) User click image in the collection view

2) Image will redirect to the next page and display the data that stored in the property list. The data is display according to the image that they click.

I'm using Xcode 6.

How can I perform such process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CollectionView-Simple/Listings/CollectionView_ViewController_m.html) is the almost similar example give by Apple. It will give you a good point of reference.

[image: Collection View Controller]
[image: Detail View Controller]

Comment: @harry it's in objective c.

Comment: I think i know how it work..but need furthers study..because my project is in Swift language..

Comment: @harry if that is the case then you might want to take a look at the ray's tutorials: [Collection View Part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78550/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-1) and [Collection View Part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78551/beginning-ios-collection-views-swift-part-2)

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView has a delegate which provides a method

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

When an item is tapped, the function above is called. Based on indexPath you can determine which item was selected. 
In your storyboard, create a new UIViewController and create a segue from your UICollectionView to this UIViewController and make the segue as Push and name it 'collectionViewToUIViewController'.
In your didSelectItemAtIndexPath, call method

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"collectionViewToUIViewController"]
```

Also implement `prepareForSegue` where you tell the UIViewController what to display.

Comment: @harry Yes that code in Objective-C. Its swift equivalent is pretty straightforward as well.